# unable to store image in specific folder in sd card

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdcard

I am capturing image by camera app and want to store in Specific folder but image not storing in folder here is my code :

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + "my_data");
                try {
                    if (!dir.exists())
                        if (dir.mkdir()) {
                            System.out.println("Directory created");
                            Toast.makeText(Add.this, "created dir",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    image_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/my_data/" + aa + "_image.jpg";
                    File file = new File(dir,image_path);

                    uriImage = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImage);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: have u declared permissions

Comment: yes i have permissions .

Comment: What are you testing the app on? If it's an emulator, try remounting the sd card along with write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

This should work, if not please post logcat output.

```
     String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + java.io.File.separator + "my_data"
                        );
     File dir = new File(folderPath);
     if(!dir.exists){
        dir.mkdirs();
       }

    imagePath = folderPath+java.io.File.separator+aa+"_image.jpg";
```